# how to generate md5 hash in angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular

I am using APi The access to this api is done with hash key that we need to send to the api but we don't really know how to implement.

I found  https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js      but  i dont know how to integrate angular 2

also  i found https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-md5   but i dont know how to import using angular 2 typscript

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For angular 2 use

```
npm install ts-md5 --save
```

then import it into component, service or wherever you want

```
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
```

When you are using **systemJS** is neccessary set map and package paths.

```
 map:      {
              'ts-md5': 'src/js/ts-md5',
           },
 packages: {
              'ts-md5': {main: '/md5.js'},                
           }
```

This is the example from one of my project where I copy neccessary libraries to separate file structure.

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds Int32Array.toString()

Answer (score 11):

You can get a md5.ts file here:

https://github.com/ManvendraSK/angular2-quickstart/blob/master/app/md5.ts

import it in your component/service:

```
import {md5} from './md5'; //make sure it points to the folder where the md5.ts file is
```

then you can use it in your component/service:

```
let e = md5(this.email);
```

Comment: The link to the blog article seems to be dead. Please update if possible, or remove the link.

Comment: @Dr.Coconut, link seems to be working fine. Try again. Maybe an issue on your end.

Comment: The link is always redirecting me to the base page of the Blog (http://www.tothenew.com/blog/)

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz you are right, the blog no longer exists. Initially I thought you meant the link to the source code (even though you clearly said link to blog). I've removed the link as I can't find the blog anywhere