# How to compute the hash of a file with angular-file-md5 in a given JHipster webapp based on angular 6?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have tried to use the angular-file-md5 library but i am still not able to follow its readme, perhaps due toi the fact I am not an expert on angular.
I have created a small github project, where i have generated a basic web app based on jhipster framework (angular 6).

https://github.com/flefevre/jhipsterangularjsmd5/tree/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/filehash

but I do not where I have to add the readme code

```
angular.module('yourApp')
.controller('yourController', ['fileMd5Service', function(fileMd5Service) {
    this.hashFile = function(file) {
        fileMd5Service.md5(file)
        .progress(function(stats) {
            console.log('Hashed ' + stats.loaded + ' B out of ' + stats.total + ' B');
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log('Error calculating md5: %o', error);
        }).success(function(md5sum) {
            console.log('MD5 for ' + file.name + ' is ' + md5sum);
        });
    };
}]);
```

in which file

- filehash-update.component.html    adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash-update.component.ts  adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash.component.html   adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash.component.ts adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash.module.ts    adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash.route.ts adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- filehash.service.ts   adding the basic entity file    3 minutes ago
- index.ts  adding the basic entity file

Do you have any advice?
Thanks

Comment: looks like angularJS not angular

Comment: Use a library that is made for angular not angularjs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299630/how-to-generate-md5-hash-in-angular-2-typescript

Comment: Thanks for the link, based on your element I have create a more clear question, due to the fact it is linked with jhispter and angulkar 5/6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334539/where-to-code-the-md5-of-file-with-ng-jhipster-in-the-client-browser-side

Comment: Finaly I have succeed. (no way to answer to my own question / i have been ban?!) 

You need to install ts-md5 in your project

```
npm install ts-md5
```

Then with jhipster you create an entity of type Blob

```
entity Filehash (filehash) {
  name String,
  hashOfFile String,
  contentOfFile AnyBlob
}
```

You create the different UI code

```
jhipster import-jdl ./my-jdl-file.jdl 
```

You update the code of FilehashUpdateComponent

    import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
    const toto = '' + Md5.hashStr('toto' + this.filehash.contentOfFile);


That's it.